# WSUS 3.0 SP2 installation fails at "configuring database" step

Tags: sql-server-2005, wsus

Attempting to install WSUS 3.0 SP2 on a Windows Server 2003 Enterprise system. I'm asking the setup to create a new database on one of our existing SQL Server 2005 systems. When the setup gets to the "configuring database" step it stops and throws "There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor." The two logs it suggests I look at are below. I'm not seeing any errors that mean anything to me.

Any direction you can give will be greatly appreciated.

**WSUSSetup.log:**

2009-12-04 15:26:21  Success   MWUSSetup          Validating pre-requisites...
2009-12-04 15:26:22  Error     MWUSSetup          Failed to determine if an higher version of WSUS is installed. Assuming it is not... (Error 0x80070002: The system cannot find the file specified.)
2009-12-04 15:26:28  Success   MWUSSetup          No SQL instances found
2009-12-04 15:26:42  Success   MWUSSetup          Initializing installation details
2009-12-04 15:26:42  Success   MWUSSetup          Installing ASP.Net
2009-12-04 15:27:24  Success   MWUSSetup          ASP.Net is installed successfully
2009-12-04 15:27:24  Success   MWUSSetup          Installing WSUS...
2009-12-04 15:27:28  Success   CustomActions.Dll  Unable to get INSTALL_LANGUAGE property, calculating it...
2009-12-04 15:27:28  Success   CustomActions.Dll  Successfully set propery of WSUS admin groups' full names
2009-12-04 15:27:29  Success   CustomActions.Dll  .Net framework path: C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727
2009-12-04 15:27:33  Success   CustomActions.Dll  Creating user group: WSUS Reporters with Description: WSUS Administrators who can only run reports on the Windows Server Update Services server.
2009-12-04 15:27:33  Success   CustomActions.Dll  Creating WSUS Reporters user group
2009-12-04 15:27:33  Success   CustomActions.Dll  WSUS Reporters user group already exists
2009-12-04 15:27:33  Success   CustomActions.Dll  Successfully created WSUS Reporters user group
2009-12-04 15:27:33  Success   CustomActions.Dll  Creating user group: WSUS Administrators with Description: WSUS Administrators can administer the Windows Server Update Services server.
2009-12-04 15:27:33  Success   CustomActions.Dll  Creating WSUS Administrators user group
2009-12-04 15:27:33  Success   CustomActions.Dll  WSUS Administrators user group already exists
2009-12-04 15:27:33  Success   CustomActions.Dll  Successfully created WSUS Administrators user group
2009-12-04 15:27:33  Success   CustomActions.Dll  Successfully created WSUS user groups
2009-12-04 15:27:33  Success   CustomActions.Dll  Succesfully set binary SID property
2009-12-04 15:27:33  Success   CustomActions.Dll  Succesfully set binary SID property
2009-12-04 15:27:33  Success   CustomActions.Dll  Successfully set binary SID properties
2009-12-04 15:28:50  Error     MWUSSetup          InstallWsus: MWUS Installation Failed (Error 0x80070643: Fatal error during installation.)
2009-12-04 15:28:50  Error     MWUSSetup          CInstallDriver::PerformSetup: WSUS installation failed (Error 0x80070643: Fatal error during installation.)
2009-12-04 15:28:50  Error     MWUSSetup          CSetupDriver::LaunchSetup: Setup failed (Error 0x80070643: Fatal error during installation.)

**From the end of WSUSSetupmsi_091204_1527.log**

MSI (s) (58:7C) [15:28:49:860]: Note: 1: 1708
MSI (s) (58:7C) [15:28:49:860]: Product: Windows Server Update Services 3.0 SP2 -- Installation failed.

MSI (s) (58:7C) [15:28:49:875]: Cleaning up uninstalled install packages, if any exist
MSI (s) (58:7C) [15:28:49:875]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
MSI (s) (58:78) [15:28:49:985]: Destroying RemoteAPI object.
MSI (s) (58:90) [15:28:49:985]: Custom Action Manager thread ending.
=== Logging stopped: 12/4/2009  15:28:49 ===
MSI (c) (30:54) [15:28:50:016]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (30:54) [15:28:50:016]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
=== Verbose logging stopped: 12/4/2009  15:28:50 ===

Answer (score 1):

I've found it's much easier to install WSUS to the Win Internal Database then move the DB to another SQL server. Here's the [MS article on moving the DB after the fact](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc708558%28WS.10%29.aspx). I've done this several times and it works like a charm every time.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the wsusca.log files this is a partial guess, but it sounds like the user you are using does not have permissions to the sql server you are trying to use.

Check out [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/920660) technet article on the subject.

Comment: I saw that article and checked to make sure that the user I wam logged in as to install WSUS is indeed granted the sysadmin role on the SQL server. Where do I find wsusca.log? This was not in the %temp% folder where the other logs were stored. Thanks.

Comment: If i remember correctly (it's been a while since I installed WSUS) it's either in the root of C:\ or in C:\windows

Comment: "2009-12-04 15:26:28 Success MWUSSetup No SQL instances found"
Does the SQL server have TCP/IP and Named access enabled? Are you using a named instance and just forgot to include it in the WSUS setup?